# C Function returning pointers - memory fault, core dumped

Tags: c

Please, can someone tell me why the program below compiles but when I try to run it I receive the error message that there has been memory fault? 
The program does not even exercise the first line of the main function. I put printf line at the beginning of the main function, but it is not executed.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


 typedef struct element {
   struct element *next;
   struct element *previous;
   char imie[256];
   char nazwisko[256];
   char tytul[256];
   int numer;
   double cena;     
 } el_listy;


el_listy* tworzpierwszy(el_listy *nowy){
   nowy=(el_listy*)realloc(nowy, sizeof(el_listy));
   strcpy(nowy->imie,"");
   strcpy(nowy->nazwisko,"");
   strcpy(nowy->tytul,"");
   nowy->numer=0;
   nowy->cena=0.00;
   nowy->next=NULL;
   nowy->previous=NULL;
   return nowy;
}


 void addoddolu (el_listy *lista){
   el_listy *wsk, *nowy;
   wsk = lista;
   while (wsk->next != NULL)
     { 
     wsk = wsk->next; /* przesuwamy wsk aż znajdziemy ostatni element */
     }
   nowy =(el_listy*) malloc (sizeof(el_listy));
   char bufor[256];
   int nm;
   double no;
   printf("Podaj imie autora ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->imie,bufor);};
   printf("Podaj nazwisko autora ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->nazwisko, bufor);};
   printf("Podaj tytul ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->tytul, bufor);};
   printf("Podaj numer katalogowy ksiazki");
   if(scanf("%d", &nm)==1){nowy->numer=nm;};
   printf("Podaj cene ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%lf", &no)==1){nowy->cena=no;};
   nowy->next = NULL;
   nowy->previous=wsk;
   wsk->next = nowy; /* podczepiamy nowy element do ostatniego z listy */
 }

void addodgory (el_listy *lista){
   el_listy *wsk, *nowy;
   char bufor[256];
   int nm;
   double no;
   wsk = lista;
   nowy =(el_listy*) malloc (sizeof(el_listy));
   printf("Podaj imie autora ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->imie,bufor);};
   printf("Podaj nazwisko autora ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->nazwisko, bufor);};
   printf("Podaj tytul ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->tytul, bufor);};
   printf("Podaj numer katalogowy ksiazki");
   if(scanf("%d", &nm)==1){nowy->numer=nm;};
   printf("Podaj cene ksiazki > ");
   if(scanf("%lf", &no)==1){nowy->cena=no;};
   nowy->previous = NULL;
   nowy->next=wsk;
   wsk->previous = nowy; /* podczepiamy nowy element do ostatniego z listy */
 }

 void wypiszliste(el_listy *lista){
   el_listy *wsk=lista;
   int numer=1;
   while( wsk != NULL )
     {
     printf ("Ksiazka %d, %s, %s, %s, %d, %lf \n", numer, wsk->imie, wsk->nazwisko, wsk->tytul, wsk->numer, wsk->cena);
     numer=numer+1;
     wsk = wsk->next;
     }
 }

void usunzlisty(el_listy *lista, int numer){
   el_listy *wsk=lista;
   while (wsk->next != NULL)
     {
     if (wsk->next->numer == numer) /* musimy mieć wskaźnik do elementu poprzedzającego */
       {
       el_listy *usuwany=wsk->next; /* zapamiętujemy usuwany element */
       wsk->next = usuwany->next;   /* przestawiamy wskaźnik next by omijał usuwany element */
       usuwany->next->previous=wsk;
       free(usuwany);               /* usuwamy z pamięci */
       } else
         {
         wsk = wsk->next;           /* idziemy dalej tylko wtedy kiedy nie usuwaliśmy */
         }                          /* bo nie chcemy zostawić duplikatów */
       }
 }

 int szukaj_nazwisko(el_listy *lista, char* nazwisko){
   el_listy *wsk;
   wsk = lista;
   while (wsk != NULL) {
     if (strcmp(wsk->nazwisko,nazwisko)==0) return wsk->numer;
        wsk = wsk->next;
     }
     return 0;
 }

 int main (){
   printf("Program glowny, pierwszy wiersz");
   el_listy *wskaznik;
   printf("Program glowny, drugi wiersz");
   el_listy* lista;
   lista = tworzpierwszy(wskaznik);
   addodgory(lista);
   wypiszliste(lista);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: always check the returned value from the malloc family of functions to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the stdout is buffered, the buffer is only sent to the terminal when the buffer is getting full.  To force immediate output to the terminal, either end the printf format string with '\n' or (better) follow each printf with 'fflush(stdout);'

Comment: regarding this kind of line: if(scanf("%s", bufor)==1){strcpy(nowy->imie,bufor);};  No limit has been put on the number of characters the user can enter, so a buffer overrun can easily occur, which is undefined behaviour, leading to a seg fault event.

Comment: a couple of problems: 1) if the call to realloc() fails, then (in the current code) the prior pointer to allocated memory would be lost, resulting in a memory leak.  Best to check the returned value before assigning it to the pointer.  2) realloc, (in the current code) is trying to add to the size of the allocated memory, but fails to increase the size.  suggest passing a second parameter that indicates the current size then if(NULL == (temp_listy = realloc(nowy, sizeof(el_listy)*(secondParameter+1)) ) ){// handle error} else {nowy = temp_list;}

Comment: setting a char array via: 'strcpy(nowy->imie,"");' is not a good idea.  much better to use: 'memset( nowy->imie, 0x00, sizeof( nowy->imie) );'  as that clears the whole field, not just set the first char to '\0'

Comment: when declaring a pointer variable, it is best to always set it some initial value.  If no reasonable value exists, then set it to NULL.

Comment: Tip: use the `-Wall` option. GCC gives this warning with that option: `C:\so-test\test.c:121:10: warning: 'wskaznik' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`.  Also on Linux `valgrind` is an easy to use tool (even if the diagnostics aren't  always easy to understand) for debugging memory problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't called `malloc()` for `wskaznik` in `main()`. It should look something like:

```
el_listy *wskaznik = (el_listy *) malloc(sizeof(struct element));
```

Comment: Or even just `el_listy *wskaznik = 0;` since `realloc()` will happily work with a null pointer as its first argument.  (Actually, `realloc()` can be used to allocate memory anew, free memory, increase the size of a previous allocation or decrease the size of a previous allocation — an all-in-one memory allocation system!  It's best not to use it for freeing memory completely, though.  The self-starting mechanism using a null pointer on the first call can be useful, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Change this line in function `tworzpierwszy`

```
nowy=(el_listy*)realloc(nowy, sizeof(el_listy));
```

into

```
nowy=(el_listy*)malloc(sizeof(el_listy));
```

and it will work !

Comment: This is a better solution, but with the change, the argument to `tworzpierwszy()` becomes superfluous; it doesn't matter what its value is on entry to the function. So, the function should become `el_listy *tworzpierwszy(void) { el_listy *nowy = malloc(sizeof(*nowy)); …; return nowy; }` and the calls change too. I'm not rabidly against casts on the result of `malloc()` for various reasons (including old age), but I protect myself by always compiling with options such that if `malloc()` (or any other function, come to that) is not declared before it is used or defined, my compilation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

`tworzpierwszy` is trying to reallocate a pointer which was never allocated, or even initialized in any way (`wskaznik`).